# Why there is no open source framework (like Java) for C# application development?

Tags: c#, java, open-source, frameworks

C# is much more popular than Java in recent years. As a general-purpose programming language, many people feel that C# is better designed than Java.

Why until now there is no open source framework for C# application development? Why no one take the initiative to develop a open source framework for C# which is comparable to Java?

(Many people say Mono is not a mature framework and should not be used in serious application development.)

Comment: I just wanted too disagree with your statement about C# being more popular than Java ... Look at this ...
http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html

Comment: @Romain it depends on how you define "popular". Most jobs is one way. New projects is another. Etc. Normally these kinds of statements are subject to closure for being subjective and argumentative. I don't think the OP's wording is inflammatory/incendiary however but it might be worth restating a little.

Comment: @Romain: Of course, "most searches" does not mean "most-used language" - when programming in C I make about 5x as many google searches than when programming in C# :)  I also make probably 50x more searches than when programming in Python, so I am surprised that Python is so high on the TIOBE list

Comment: .NET is a provided by one company.  This does not attact developers who would write a major open source solution.

Comment: @Peter - that is in part because .NET is a Microsoft *brand* ; there are, however, several CLI implementations - not *just* Mono.

Comment: @Marc, then perhaps there is a perception problem. In any case I don't believe there is a good technical reason .NET doesn't attract as many open source developers.

Comment: I have to defend Mono on this one. Of course, if you compare it against .NET in case of compatibility it isn't quiet what it should be, but if you look at it as independent framework which happens to have *basic* (as in 3.0...or was it 3.5?) compatibility support for .NET applications, it's great. It also does have some libraries which .NET lacks, f.e. Cecil.

Answer (score 9):

Not really sure what the question is - are you asking why there is no open source version of the full .net framework?

The answer is that the framework is HUGE, involving the full-time commitment of literally thousands of people.  Replicating all that - including the bugs - so that .net programs could be reliably run across all platforms is simply impossible.

However, implementations of the base-class library (BCL) are available.  Aside from [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page), there is also [DotGNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/dotgnu/)

In addition, [parts of the .net library itself](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8c09fd61-3f26-4555-ae17-3121b4f51d4d&displaylang=en) are "open source," though not in the traditional sense (the source can be viewed, but not used).

Answer (score 6):

While some people might claim that Mono is not mature enough for production code, that doesn't change the fact that Mono *is* an open-source framework for C# development, so the claim in your question's title is clearly not correct.

As to why there are no other open-source C# (.NET) frameworks around -- why should anyone bother creating a 2nd open-source .NET platform from scratch when they could just as easily invest their time in improving Mono? Do we really need two open-source .NET platforms?

> ***Update:** When I wrote this answer, I didn't yet know that some people at Microsoft actually did put out a sort-of open-source implementation of the CLI: the [Shared Source CLI (SSCLI)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=8c09fd61-3f26-4555-ae17-3121b4f51d4d&displaylang=en), also known as Rotor. In hindsight, I think this deserves a mention here, to support the argument by others that there are other alternative CLI implementations apart from Mono.*

Apart from those considerations, I think this question probably asks for fairly subjective answers.

Answer (score 4):

I'd be interested in who those "Many people" are; Mono is a considerable achievement, with serious backing (Novell) and also gets assistance from Microsoft. It *is* used in many serious and commercial applications. There would be little benefit in duplicating this huge amount of work.

The Mono CLI implementation is pretty solid. There are certainly some gaps in libraries (WPF, for example) - but that is a strategic decision; the plan there is to track Silverlight, and bring Moonlight up until the *inevitable* point when WPF and Silverlight  are largely indistinguishable.

There are also several things that are *in advance* of Microsoft's .NET implementation; full AOT, for example, or the compiler-as-a-service (managed compiler).

You have mono on the server, on the desktop, in the browser (Moonlight) and on the mobile (Android and iPhone, 3.3.1 aside) - possibly other places too.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because most open source projects get started because there isn't a similar product available or in some cases a free product.  In this case Visual Studio Express editions are very capable and free so there's not the incentive to create an open source development tool as there are in other languages/platforms.  I expect if Express goes away or starts to have a cost associated with it then an open source project will develop.